# What is executed (explicitly and implicitly) in parallell and what sequentially in node.js?

Tags: node.js, event-handling, parallel-processing, promise

This example confuse my understanding of how the `node.js` works:

```
// 1.
numbers.forEach(function(number) {
  queue.push(Q.call(slowFunction, this, number));
});

// 2.
// Q.all: execute an array of 'promises' and 'then' call either a resolve 
// callback (fulfilled promises) or reject callback (rejected promises)
Q.all(queue).then(function(ful) {

  // All the results from Q.all are on the argument as an array
  console.log('fulfilled', ful);
}, function(rej) {

  // The first rejected (error thrown) will be here only
  console.log('rejected', rej);
}).fail(function(err) {

  // If something went wrong, then we catch it here, usually when there is no
  // rejected callback.
  console.log('fail', err);
}).fin(function() {

  // Finally statement; executed no matter of the above results
  console.log('finally');
});
```

Why it is assumed here, that `1.` and `2.` parts of code will be executed sequentially?
So, where is the guarantee that `Q.all(queue)` works on all `queue` elements pushed in `1.`? Could it be so, that the `numbers` from `1.` is so big, that it works than parallel to `2.`?
These ideas coming from the understanding that node.js will handling `1.` and `2.` first of all with the `node.js event-loop` and then give it to `workers`, which are actually analogue to the normal threads.

So the question - will be `1.` and `2.` executed parallel to each other, started from `node.js event-loop` sequentially or will they be executed sequentially (the `1.` push all elements in the queue and only after that the `2.` starts to handling each element in the `queue`) ?
Please provide arguments with some direct links to documentation for this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the topmost level, 1. and 2's `Q.all(queue).then(...).fail(...).fin(...);` method chain, will unambiguously be executed sequentially.

The precise timing of execution of functions defined/called within 1 and 2 depends very much on the nature of `slowFunction`.

- If `slowFunction` is performed wholly by synchronous javascript (eg. some extensive Math), then 1 will have completed in its entirety before 2 starts. In this case the callbacks specified in 2 will execute very shortly after 2's method chain has finished executing because any promises returned by `slowfunction` will be (or at least should be) already resolved.
- If however, `slowFunction` involves one or more asynchronous node I/O process (eg. file handling or resource fetching), then each call to it will (at least in part) be undertaken by a non-blocking worker thread (not javascript); in this case, providing `slowFunction` is correctly written, `queue` will accumulate a set of promises, each of which will be resolved or rejected later. The callbacks specified in 2 will execute after 2's method chain has finished executing AND when all the promises have been either resolved or rejected.

For me, a rephrased version of 2's introductory text would go a long way toward explaining the order of execution :

> Q.all: Wait for every 'promise' in the `queue` array of to be either
>   resolved or rejected 'then' call the corresponding callback function.

Ref: http://rickgaribay.net/archive/2012/01/28/node-is-not-single-threaded.aspx